# Does randomization make a big difference in the output of the BKZ algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-design, randomness, lattice-crypto, lenstra-lenstra-lovasz

We all know that [block Korkine-Zolotarev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korkine%E2%80%93Zolotarev_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) (BKZ) algorithm  is essentially a deterministic [lattice reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction) algorithm. However, in the actual implementation, the [BKZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korkine%E2%80%93Zolotarev_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) algorithm contains some randomization, For example, the actual algorithm will do some random unimodular transformations on the lattice basis in order to obtain a better reduced basis. I wonder if this subtle change will make a big difference to the final output. Does it?

Comment: How would one quantify such difference?

Comment: one quantity is using the length of the shortest vector in the reduced basis